# bursty streaming video

Tags: ubuntu, video-streaming

What is the cause and solution for the bursty streaming media problem?  Example: when streaming from youtube, audio (and video) will pause and start intermittently.  When it starts it will be bursty, that is, it will play several seconds of sound in just a fraction of a second.  Normal sounds are rendered unrecognizable.  Then it may pause and after a few seconds, resume with another burst.  The video seems to burst along with the audio.

This was observed on Ubuntu 12.04 with Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`killall pulseaudio`

`pulseaudio`

fixes the problem.